# WPF find control under mouse without modifying the application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm creating a log system ('outside' the application) that logs all the click on the application. I have setup a `PreFilterMessage` function wich detects a click from the mouse, but I can't find the control/element that was clicked.

I've tried with `Mouse.DirectlyOver`but the element is always `null`.
I've tried also with `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` but I don't have a `Visual`to make the search from.

I don't have access to the inside of the application: only to the Main method (with the `Application.Run(new MainForm());` and my `Application.AddMessageFilter(new Logger());`).

Does anyone have an idea (or a walk around) on how to get the clicked control in the application (in .Net 3.5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using an amazing little application called Snoop for some time now that I think does exactly what you're after, it's open source (C#) and may be of use to you if you can find out how it works. (All WPF developers should get this and no I don't work on Snoop lol)

http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Snoop works by injecting its own assembly into the snooped process, allowing you to use `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` and such. I think it's a good starting point.